# I want to send multiple records to multiple receipts in a single email

Tags: php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )
*/
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler; 

$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['fname','cnic','email','cell'])->areRequired()->maxLength(100);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();


$pp->sendEmailTo('sasbukhari96@gmail.com','email'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is right method but you can up to 50 emails in BCC tested by phpmailer (not sure if more/less, this much work on my host). Add receiver as some your no-reply address and bcc to other emails.

Comment: Please explain where and what the fail point was in your code, based on your debugging so far.

Comment: There are multiple form group in my html code against same variable now I dont know how to do php